# Tabulator , Is there a way of adding sum of page to the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

`Tabulator` have a module named `Column Calculations`.

I need to add both `sum of page` and `sum of total`

[image: Sample Image of sum of page and sum of total]

I can add footer for calculate `sum of total` for example, but I can't add `sum of visible rows` or in another words `sum of current page only` in same time.

I can add a footer to `bottom` or `top` of the table : `topCalc`& `bottomCalc` .

For example I can add `sum` of `price`.

As you can see in the example below , I added sum of price here.

Also I put the example here : https://jsfiddle.net/o2ycm5dp/

```js
function generateTable(data) {
  tableInstance = new Tabulator("#simpleTable", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    resizableColumns: false,
    selectable: false,
    paginationSize: 3,
    responsiveLayout: "hide",
    ajaxFiltering: false,
    pagination: "local",
    columns: [{
        title: "name",
        field: "name",
      },
      {
        title: "price",
        field: "price",
        bottomCalc: "sum",
      },

    ],
  });
  tableInstance.setData(data);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var data =     [{
    name: "Tiger Nixon",
    price: "320800"
}, {
    name: "Garrett Winters",
    price: "170750"
}, {
    name: "Ashton Cox",
    price: "86000"
}, {
    name: "Cedric Kelly",
    price: "433060"
}, {
    name: "Airi Satou",
    price: "162700"
}, {
    name: "Brielle Williamson",
    price: "372000"
}, {
    name: "Herrod Chandler",
    price: "137500"
}];
  generateTable(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="simpleTable"></div>
```

On this line : `bottomCalc: "sum",` , calculation function will called and we can see the `sum` of `price` column.

There is an option named `Custom Calculations` which I can add a function to calculate only `current page values`, but I can't have the calculation of `total pages values`.

Another solution maybe `append` an html element to the footer but I don't think it could be a good solution. Because I should handle all those functions related to `Tabulator` footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabulator does not have the ability to layout the table as you request. you would need to manually create a footer element to handle this, and then use the [Pagination Callbacks](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/callbacks#page) to work out the values to show

Comment: As you mentioned here : https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2579 tabulator does not have a solution yet for this. What I did was adding a custom footer generator. I handle lots of code in my "CustomTabulator", so I have a new method that orchestrate what I need and generate a table that match my needs.